# Troubles with adding permission to bucket policy s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a little problem with my code. Basically I should have permission to delete a bucket but it's not working. Do you have any idea why isn't it working?

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAcces",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::...",
                "...",
                "arn:aws:iam::...",
                "arn:aws:iam::...",
                "arn:aws:iam::...",
                "arn:aws:iam::..."
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::.../*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::..."
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Are there any other policy statements?  A deny always prevails over an allow, for example.

Comment: It came out that I was operating on an old policy, the new version was implemented and it's working...